# Накладываются картинки Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

При написании текста на картинке таким кодом:

```
def drawimg(picture1, text, x, y):
    img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(picture1)
    img_draw.text((x, y), text = text, font = font, fill = 'black')
    img.save('C:\\Users\\Администратор\\Desktop\\Python\\VimeBot\\Stats\\picture2.png')
```

Оно просто накладывает старую версию picture2 на новую.
Как с этим быть?

Comment: Вы сохраняете не ту картинку

Answer (score 0):

Вы сохраняете не то изображение. По факту, объекта `img` впринципе нет у Вас в коде.
В своей функции вы редактируете изображение `picture1`, так и сохраняйте то, что редактируете. А именно:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def drawing(picture1, text, x, y):
    img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(picture1) # Вы создали инструмент, который редактирует picture1
    img_draw.text((x, y), text = text, font = font, fill = 'black') # Пририсовали текст
    picture1.save("PATH") # И сохранили.


img = Image.open("PATH_TO_THE_IMAGE")

drawing(img, "This is test text", 200, 200)
```